# Page-level custom variable not showing in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have some custom variables set up in Google Analytics (async snippet), configured per their instructions like so:

```
_gaq.push('_setCustomVar', 2, 'price','5800', 3);
_gaq.push('_setCustomVar', 2, 'city','New York', 3);
_gaq.push('_setCustomVar', 2, 'neighborhood','West Village', 3);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

But when I go to the reports, these variables don't show up. How do you access them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 5 slots and need to assign a variable to each slot. The current code will just send the last one as it overwrites previous one and occupies slot #2. You can use a slot to each and it should work from there.

```
_gaq.push('_setCustomVar', 1, 'price','5800', 3);
_gaq.push('_setCustomVar', 2, 'city','New York', 3);
_gaq.push('_setCustomVar', 3, 'neighborhood','West Village', 3);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

To view this data just create a Custom Report like the one below.

[image]

And here is a [link to this Custom Report](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=S10h60t4TOOUqAIaKFg9Gg). You can also play with the order you use to drill down from one CV into the other.

Comment: How do you view the reports with this info?

Comment: @Avishai Added instructions to the answer